# pandas.io.ga not returning object

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am running a pandas.io.ga query and absolutely no object is being returned? I have copied the secret_clients.json file to two folders just to be safe because I don't know which pandas/io folder to do it to, i suspect the problem is that it can't find the client_secrets.json file - but with NO ERROR at all I have no clue?!

sudo cp ~/Desktop/client_secrets.json /Users/atrombley/anaconda/pkgs/pandas-0.14.1-np19py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/

sudo cp ~/Desktop/client_secrets.json /Users/atrombley/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd; import pandas.io.ga as ga; import os
print ga.read_ga(
account_id  = "private",
property_id = "private",
metrics     = ['users', 'pageviews'],
dimensions  = ['dayOfWeek'],
start_date  = "2015-01-01",
end_date    = "2015-01-02",
index_col   = 0,
)
>>> ## THIS IS JUST BLANK?  NOTHING PRINTED?
```

Comment: Did you check the same query using the [Query Feed Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/)? Does it return a valid response?